# Directory tree representation with double linked list

Tags: javascript, linked-list, file-system

```
var root = this;
root.node = function(path, type) {
  root.type = type;
  this.type = type;
   this.parents = [];
   this.children = [];
   var components = path.split('/');
   this.parents = parseParents(components);
   this.name = components[components.length - 1];
   this.addChild = function(path, type){
              if(this.type === 'file'){
                throw new Error('A file node cannot have any children');
              }
              this.children.push(new root.node(path, type));
  }

  function parseParents(components){

        var parents = [];
        if(components.length > 0){
           for(var i = (components.length - 1); i > 0; i--){
              if(components[i] !== "")
                if(parents.length === 0){
                  var currentParent = new node(components[i], 'dir');
                  currentParent.children.push(new node(components[0], root.type));
                  parents.push(currentParent); 
                }
                else{
                  var newParent = new node(components[i], 'dir');
                  var curretnChild = new node(components[i - 1], 'dir');
                  currentParent.parents.push(newParent);
                  currentParent = newParent;
                }
           }
           return parents;
         }
         return [];

   }
   return this;
}

var a = new node('/usr/local/foo', 'dir');
a.addChild('test', 'file');
console.log(a);
```

2 way linked list, works great besides that the the 'leaf' items are not populated currently, since in the current structure it will result in an infinite loop.

You thoughts please.

Comment: If leaf items are not populated and it goes into an infinite loop, then your code does not work and hence does not belong on CR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this question is valid, but there is reviewable code:

- `node` is a constructor, it should be named with an uppercase `N`
- `curretnChild` is not properly spelled, and not used anywhere, drop it
- Since you set `parents` to `[]`, you might as well return `parents` when `if(components.length > 0){` is not true
- You should declare your `var`s on top in `parseParents`, the scope of `newParent` and `currentParent` is the whole function anyway
- Your reliance on `root.type` is a bug in waiting, find a better way to figure out what the type should be.
- `addChild` should be part of `Node.prototype`, it does not make sense for every instance of `Node` to have it's own version of this function
- Your code in `addChild` does not take care of dupes, that should be addressed

For fun, I  wrote this, it creates a double linked list and takes most of my comments in to consideration, except for the last one ( does not take care of dupes ).

```
function Node( path , type )
{
  var parts = this.cleanPathParts( path.split("/") ),
      part  = parts.pop();
  //Set the basics
  this.name = part;
  this.type = type;
  //Do we still have parts left ?
  if( parts.length ){
    this.parent = new Node( parts.join('/'), this.DIR );
    this.parent.children = [ this ];
  }
}
//Ignore blanks and `..` strings
Node.prototype.cleanPathParts = function( parts )
{
  return parts.filter( function(part){
    return !!part && part != "..";
  });
};
//Get the ultimate parent, usefull for adding path children
Node.prototype.getRoot = function()
{
  var root = this;
  while( root.parent )
    root = root.parent;
  return root;
};
//Add a child, either a simple node or a path
Node.prototype.addChild = function( part , type )
{
  if( this.type != this.DIR ){
      throw new Error('A file node cannot have any children');
  }
  var node = (new Node( part, type )).getRoot();
  node.parent = this;
  this.children = this.children || [];
  this.children.push( node );
};
//Constants
Node.prototype.DIR  = 'dir';           
Node.prototype.FILE = 'file'; 

var a = new Node('/usr/local/foo', 'dir');
a.addChild('1/2/test', 'file');
a.addChild('test', 'file');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: It's not 2 ways list though, if the children don't point back to the father :P

Comment: the property `parent` should do the trick?